# Appending Spaces for textview in Android

Tags: java, android

I've written an android application to send text to a local device via Bluetooth protocol. I've set the maximum length of input field as shown below.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_out_r3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            tools:phoneNumber="true" />
```

Now i wish to append spaces at the beginning of the string if the entered string has length less than max length.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple steps:- Check the length, check how less than required one, Append that much spaces at the beginning of input.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will add the necessary left padding of spaces.

```
EditText edit_text_out_r3ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out_r3);

String currentString= edit_text_out_r3ET.getText().toString();

    int wantedStringLength=8;
    int difference;

    difference = wantedStringLength - currentString.length();

        for ( int i=0; i<difference; i++) {
          currentString=” “+currentString;
        }
```